# Struct function returns incomplete type

Tags: c, struct

In header.h I have:

```
typedef struct {
    int score;
    int dice[6];
    int scorecard[2][7];
} player;
```

Then in definitions.c I have:

```
struct player do_turn(struct player user) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        int die = roll_die();
        user.dice[i] = die;
    }
    return (user);
}
```

On the function definition I get the error "function do_turn returns incomplete type struct player"

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `struct player do_turn(struct player user)` -> `player do_turn(player user)` That's what a `typedef` is for.

Comment: in your code you typedef'd the struct as player so you cannot use struct player as datatype name instead you should use player as the struct datatype name. More broader answer you aliased your struct name as player.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This struct can (only) be accessed as `struct player`:

```
struct player {
    int score;
    int dice[6];
    int scorecard[2][7];
};

struct player do_turn(struct player user) { ... }
```

This struct can (only) be accessed as just `player`:

```
typedef struct {
    int score;
    int dice[6];
    int scorecard[2][7];
} player;

player do_turn(player user) { ... }
```

And this one can be accessed as either `player` or `struct player`:

```
typedef struct player {
    int score;
    int dice[6];
    int scorecard[2][7];
} player;

struct player do_turn(player user) { /* don't actually mix them like this :-P */ }
```

Depending on how you'd like this to look, change your struct definition, your function definition, or both, to make them match.

Answer (score 4):

Let's deconstruct the definition of `player`.

#### This is the type:

```
struct {
    int score;
    int dice[6];
    int scorecard[2][7];
}
```

It is an anonymous `struct`. While it is correct, an anonymous `struct` is not very useful because is definition cannot be reused, it has to be typed again when needed.

#### Let's add the name:

```
struct {
    int score;
    int dice[6];
    int scorecard[2][7];
} player
```

Maybe you think `player` is the name of the `struct` but this is not true. The type is the same as before (an anonymous `struct`), `player` is a variable of this type.

#### How to name the `struct`?

Adding a name to the anonymous `struct` described above is easy: put the name immediately after the `struct` keyword (before the open curly bracket):

```
struct _player {
    int score;
    int dice[6];
    int scorecard[2][7];
} player;
```

`player` is still a variable but its type now is not anonymous any more. Its type is `struct _player` (not just `_player`). The keyword `struct` is part of the name.

#### What happens when we put `typedef` in front?

```
typedef struct _player {
    int score;
    int dice[6];
    int scorecard[2][7];
} player;
```

The keyword `typedef` turns `player` into a type name (remember it is a variable in the absence of `typedef`). In the declaration above there is no variable. What it declares are the `struct _player` type and `player` that is a different name of `struct _player` (an alias).

There is no definition of `struct player` above as there is none in the code you posted. The compiler finds references to `struct player` and, apart from the information that it is a `struct`, it doesn't know anything about it. Consequently it displays the error you mentioned.